# Is it possible to use existing JavaScript objects as types in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I have an existing JavaScript object. I would like to use it in TypeScript as a type, but can't see any way to do it. For example, I have an JavaScript object constructor like this:

```
function Canvas2D(canvas)
{
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    this.clear = function() { context.clearRect(canvas.width, canvas.height); }
    // lots more methods follow...
}
```

In my TypeScript I want to declare a variable that is an instance of Canvas2D. I could define it as type "any" but that doesn't give me auto-suggest and kind of negates the benefits of using TypeScript.

```
class MyApp
{
    private canvas2d: any;
    // I want this instead
    //private canvas2d: Canvas2D;

    constructor(aCanvas) { this.canvas2d = new Canvas2D(aCanvas); }
}
```

Is there a way to do this in TypeScript?

In JavaScript I could do this:

```
var canvas2D = new Canvas2D(aCanvas);
```

And it (Visual Studio) would know what type of object it was dealing with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible. You can either port your `Canvas2D` object to a typescript class and reference the file

```
/// <reference path="Canvas2D.ts" />
```

inside of the MyApp file.

**or**

You can create a definition file (Canvas2D.d.ts) that defines the Canvas2D class shape and reference that instead.

```
/// <reference path="Canvas2D.d.ts" />
```

ex:

```
declare class Canvas2D {
    constructor(elem: HTMLCanvasElement);
    clear();
    // Lots more methods here...
}
```

Comment: thank you Ryan, learned something new about declare class vs interface :)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I was hoping it would be easier than that, so I wouldn't have to do a lot of typing ;). I don't want to rewrite Canvas2D because I use it in JavaScript apps too (I just started playing with TypeScript). I was thinking I would have to create an interface but declare looks like it might be better.